# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php, mysqli, fatal-error, easyphp

i'm working to a web app, and PHP is my backend language...

until now, i tested the website on localhost, using **easyPHP** (**PHP version 5.4.6**)...
and everything was good!
Today i tried to run the website online (**PHP version 5.3.18**), and i've this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in
>   etc.

I think this is strange, because the get_result() method should be supported since PHP 5.3.0 ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php))

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE:**

i didn't share any code because it is just fine (it still works on my localhost)... the problem should be on the online environment.

**UPDATE 2:**
I share the section of the phpInfo with the info about **mysqli**...

*Localhost:*
[image: Mysqli on localhost]

*Remote:*
[image: Mysqli online]

Comment: how about musqli version  ?

Comment: mysqli version on the online server is 5.1.66... i'm checking on the local environment

Comment: Thank you, your comment has put me on the right way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem.

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php):

> mysqli_stmt :: get_result is Available **only with mysqlnd**.

My online environment, unlike my local environment seems to be lacking of mysqlnd!

So I guess I've to contact my host.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, and I didn't have much faith that my hosting provider would enable mysqlnd anytime soon.  So ended up switching out `mysqli_stmt::get_result()`

Check if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996427/mysqli-stmt-get-result-alternative-for-php-5-2-6/13794165#13794165) works for you