# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() AND mysqlnd is installed

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

I have a problem with `get_result()` function.

The php script on my `localhost` working well but on the server have this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

I searched many times but I didn't find the solution. My code:

```
$sql=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE cat = ? order by id desc limit 10");
$cat=$_GET['cat'];
$sql->bind_param('i', $cat);
$sql->execute();
$result=$sql->get_result();
if($result){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { echo "something"; }
```

(Both "mysqli" and "mysqlnd" are installed. )

what i have to do now ?

Comment: Check with phpinfo driver of mysql.

Comment: this might  help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996427/mysqli-stmt-get-result-alternative-for-php-5-2-6/13794165#13794165)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli\_stmt::get\_result()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659856/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result) *mysqli_stmt :: get_result is Available only with mysqlnd.*

Comment: From php.ini i got this information PDO drivers sqlite, mysql

Comment: Do you have a `mysqlnd` section under `phpinfo()`?

Comment: yes i have `mysqlnd` under `phpinfo()` check this image [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GR0aZ.png)

Comment: @Machavity  did you see the image ?

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest then. If you have access to restart your web server I would try that.

Comment: i am just user on the server i don't have access to restart the server @Machavity , any other idea ? maybe the code missing something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli\_stmt::get\_result()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567335/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on Namecheap's Shared Hosting.

I solved it by switching from **mysqli** to **nd_mysqli** module in the PHP Selector in CPanel.

[image: PHP Selector configuration]

I was having the same error of get_results() seemingly not existing, but after talking to their support they confirmed it should work.

I kept playing with PHP configuration and ended up getting it to work.