# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php

My website scripts use mysqli prepared statements. They worked well on my localhost but when I uploaded the files to my hosting, it gave **"PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()"** error.

[image: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()]

I learned that mysqli prepared statements require mysqli to be enabled as API extension for mysqlnd. Checked php_info() and noticed it was not enabled on my hosting server.
[image: novalue]

Do you have any ideas how I can enable mysqli API extension for mysqlnd so that my prepared statements will work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard back from my hosting support and they confirmed that unchecking mysqli and checking nd_mysqli (Optional: unchecking pdo_mysql and checking nd_pdo_mysql) is the right way to go.

[image]
[image]

and it works correctly!