# What's going wrong?

Tags: php, mysqli

I got frustrated. I don't know what is wrong here. I can't get results from statement, but I got results from query!

```
/// query
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_token WHERE tbl_token.id = 1" ;
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $results->fetch_row();
var_dump($row); /// it works!

/// with statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_token WHERE tbl_token.id = 1");            
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->result_metadata();
$row = $result->fetch_row();
var_dump($row); /// it doesn't work. It is null.
```

My php  version is 5.5.9.

**UPDATE**

1- `fetch_field` work, but I want to get whole row here.

2- I followed **php manual** for `result_metadata`.

3- I don't knopw why `get_result()` doesn't work. Looks `mysqlnd`
is not installed. Strange for me due to my php version.

Comment: you need to utlize fetch_assoc here i believe

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php  you're fetching data **ABOUT** the result, not the actual data from the table itself. e.g. `select name from contacts` would return `name = John Doe` when you fetch a result field, while it would return `field name is "name", type is "varchar"` when you fetch metadata.

Answer (score -1):

I set up a test environment to duplicate your issue, and have found a resolution.

After running `$stmt->execute()`, you must bind the result of your statement by using `$stmt->bind_result($var);`, where `$var` is the variable that is to be filled with your MySQL row data.

After binding the result, run `$stmt->fetch();` in order to pull the result data into `$var`. After that, echoing `$var` should display the result you need.

Your new code should appear as follows:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_token WHERE tbl_token.id = 1");            
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
var_dump($result); // should display 'string(1) "1"'
```

**UPDATE**

In response to your question update, if you want to grab all of the columns from a row, then simply specify extra variables in the `$stmt->bind_result()` command. Example: `$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3)` (you may need more `$col` variables depending on how many columns you are attempting to pull data from in your table). `$stmt->fetch()` should fill all of those variables with the corresponding column data of the `fetch()`'d row. - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: thanks for your answer. actually for better understanding I din't paste whole code. I bind parameters.

Comment: Thanks for you time. but get_result doen't work here. also in my server (godaddy). I get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: The method is `get_result()` without the "s". Try removing the "s" so that way it reads `$stmt->get_result()`

Comment: same. it was my typing mistake ;)

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659856/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result